# Mutual recursion -- can someone help explain how this code works?

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm reading through "A Gentle Introduction to Haskell," and early on it uses this example, which works fine in GHC and horribly in my brain:

```
initial                 = 0
next resp               = resp
process req             = req+1

reqs                    = client initial resps
resps                   = server reqs

server          (req:reqs)   = process req : server reqs
client initial ~(resp:resps) = initial : client (next resp) resps
```

And the calling code:
`take 10 reqs`

How I'm seeing it, is `reqs` is called, yielding a call to `client` with args 0 and `resps`. Thus wouldn't `resps` now need to be called... which in turn calls `reqs` again? It all seems so infinite... if someone could detail how it's actually working, I'd be most appreciative!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I find that it's usually worthwhile to work out the behavior of small Haskell programs by hand. The evaluation rules are quite simple. The key thing to remember is that Haskell is *non-strict* (aka *lazy*): expressions are evaluated only when needed. Laziness is the reason seemingly infinite definitions can yield useful results. In this case, using `take` means we will only need the first 10 elements of the infinite list `reqs`: they are all we "need".

In practical terms, "need" is generally driven by pattern matches. E.g., a list expression will generally be evaluated up to the point where we can distinguish between `[]` and `(x:xs)` before function application. (Note that a '`~`' preceding a pattern , as in the definition of `client`, makes it lazy (or *irrefutable*): a lazy pattern won't force its argument until the whole expression is forced.)

Remembering that `take` is:

```
take 0 _      = []
take n (x:xs) = x : take (n-1) xs
```

The evaluation of `take 10 reqs` looks like:

```
take 10 reqs 
      -- definition of reqs
    = take 10 (client initial resps)
      -- definition of client [Note: the pattern match is lazy]
    = take 10 (initial : (\ resp:resps' -> client (next resp) resps') 
                             resps)
      -- definition of take
    = initial : take 9 ((\ resp:resps' -> client (next resp) resps') 
                            resps)
      -- definition of initial
    = 0 : take 9 ((\ resp:resps' -> client (next resp) resps') 
                      resps)
      -- definition of resps
    = 0 : take 9 ((\ resp:resps' -> client (next resp) resps') 
                      (server reqs))
      -- definition of reqs
    = 0 : take 9 ((\ resp:resps' -> client (next resp) resps') 
                      (server (client initial resps)))
      -- definition of client
    = 0 : take 9 ((\ resp:resps' -> client (next resp) resps') 
                      (server (initial : {- elided... -}))
      -- definition of server
    = 0 : take 9 ((\ resp:resps' -> client (next resp) resps') 
                      (process initial : server {-...-}))
      -- beta reduction 
    = 0 : take 9 (client (next (process initial)) (server {-...-})
      -- definition of client 
    = 0 : take 9 (next (process initial) : {-...-})
      -- definition of take 
    = 0 : next (process initial) : take 8 {-...-}
      -- definition of next 
    = 0 : process initial : take 8 {-...-}
      -- definition of process 
    = 0 : initial+1 : take 8 {-...-}
      -- definition of initial 
    = 0 : 1 : take 8 {-...-}
      -- and so on...
```

Comment: **Thank you!!** This is just what I needed -- evaluation truly is done in a way I wasn't expecting.

Comment: damn dude.. best explanation ever?

Answer (score 11):

Understanding this code requires two skills:

- distinguishing between 'definition', which may be infinite (like the set of natural numbers: `naturals = (1 : map '\n->n+1' naturals`), or the list of processed requests) and 'reduction', which is the process of mapping actual data to these definitions
- seeing the structure of this client-server application: it's just a pair of processes talking to eachother: 'client-server' is a bad name, really: it should have been called 'wallace-gromit' or 'foo-bar', or talking philosophers or whatever, but it's symmetrical: the two parties are peers.

As [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397341/mutual-recursion-can-someone-help-explain-how-this-code-works#397352) already stated, reduction works in a lazy way (aka 'call by need'): `take 2 naturals` would not first evaluate the complete set of naturals, but just take the first one, and prepend that to `take 1 (map '\n->n+1' naturals)`, which would reduce to [1,(1+1) ] = [1,2].

Now the structure of the client server app is this (to my eye):

- `server` is a way to create a list of responses out of a list of requests by using the `process` function
- `client` is a way to create a request based on a response, and append the response of that request to the list of responses.

If you look closely, you see that both are 'a way to create x:xs out of y:ys'.  So we could evenly call them `wallace` and `gromit`.

Now it would be easy to understand if `client` would be called with just a list of responses:

```
someresponses = wallace 0 [1,8,9]    -- would reduce to 0,1,8,9
tworesponses  = take 2 someresponses -- [0,1]
```

If the responses are not literally known, but produced by `gromit`, we can say

```
gromitsfirstgrunt = 0
otherresponses = wallace gromitsfirstgrunt (gromit otherresponses)
twootherresponses = take 2 otherresponses -- reduces to [0, take 1 (wallace (gromit ( (next 0):...) )]
                                          -- reduces to [0, take 1 (wallace (gromit ( 0:... ) )  ) ]
                                          -- reduces to [0, take 1 (wallace (1: gromit (...)  )  ) ]
                                          -- reduces to [0, take 1 (1 : wallace (gromit (...)  ) ) ]
                                          -- reduces to [0, 1 ]
```

One of both peers needs to 'start' the discussion, hence the initial value provided to `wallace`.

Also note the ~ before the pattern of `gromit`: this tells Haskell that the contents of the list argument don't need to be reduced - if it sees it's a list, that's enough.  There's a nice topic on that in a [wikibook on Haskell](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Laziness_revisited) (look for "Lazy Pattern Matching).

Comment: I knew someone much more knowledgeable than me would help out - thanks!
My uni taught Haskell in COMP 1A (to try and create a level playing ground given the vast range of experience going in), and I haven't touched it since...

Comment: Now that's a compliment!  Still, I hope someone `even more knowledgeable' would read my answer through and approve since I'm not much of a Haskell Guru myself :)

Comment: Man, I'm just too stupid to get this. I've thought about it all night and read your answer who knows how many times. I just can't see how to get to the first reduction you show. In my head it keeps panning out: wallace grunt (gromit (wallace grunt (gromit ... etc., but grunt is always 0... grrr

Answer (score 4):

It's been a while since I've played with Haskell, but I'm pretty sure that it's lazily evaluated, meaning it only calculates what it actually needs.  So while reqs is infinitely recursive, since `take 10 reqs` only needs the first 10 elements of the list returned, that is all that is actually calculated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like nice obfuscation. If you read precisely you found it simple:

next? it's identity

server? it's simply map process which is map '\n->n+1'

client? It's obscure way how to write 0 : server client e.g. 0 : map '\n->n+1' [0: map '\n->n+1' [0:...]]